# Why can't I pod install 5.0 Bigint on swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I used to use the `Bigint` version 4.0. But it tried to upgrade the version to 5.0 because it gave me a warning message.

But it shows me the error.

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "BigInt":
  In Podfile:
    BigInt (~> 5.0)

    web3.swift.pod (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
      BigInt (~> 3.1)
```

**my Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'myapp' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!

    # Pods for DeleteMe
    pod 'BigInt', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'CryptoSwift'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'web3.swift.pod', '~> 2.2.0'
end
```

[image]
What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: It's because of `web3.swift.pod`. It can't have BigInt in 4.0. You need to have the same version for them. Update https://cocoapods.org/pods/web3.swift.pod which seems to allow the 4.0 of BigInt

Comment: Hi @Larme  What version should I update to?

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/4/e/5/web3.swift.pod/2.2.1/web3.swift.pod.podspec.json : 2.2.1 & 4.0 for BigInt You can't have the 5.1 of BigInt, since Web3.swift.pod doesn't have a compatible version with it.

Comment: Can't I update Bigint then?

Comment: Except if Web3.swift.pod have a version that manage BigInt 5.0, you can't. You can use only ONE pod of each in One version. They have to be compatible between them.

Comment: @Larme If so, is it okay if I modify the warning message that I see when I build?

Comment: What warnings do you have? We can't guess what's wrong, I don't want to download all your pods to get a similar situation and guess what's your issue.

Comment: @Larme There are 5 warning messages.   'enumerateBytes' is deprecated: use `regions` or `for-in` instead

Comment: Two : 'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

Comment: Three: 'index(where:)' is deprecated: renamed to 'firstIndex(where:)' ...etc

Comment: Can I modify these warning messages myself?

Comment: Not recommanded, the files will be changed on next pod update. You can ask for an update: like this one did: https://github.com/matter-labs/web3swift/issues/207 But they are just depreciation messages. It still work as before. Wait for a future update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was, as @Larme said, a module dependency problem. The module in question is the Web3 module. It was not possible to install Bigint5 because the Web3 module still relies on Bigint4. I think we'll have to wait for a new version of this problem.